# expression is of wrong type

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a function that returns all values of the emp table Why do I get the error?

[image]

```
create or replace FUNCTION EMP_value 
RETURN VARCHAR2
is
CURSOR a is select * from emp;
v_all  emp%rowtype;
begin
open a;
LOOP
fetch a into v_all;
exit when a%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(v_all.empno|| '  ' ||v_all.ename|| '  ' ||v_all.sal);
RETURN V_ALL;
end loop;
close a;
end;
```

Comment: so what did you see when you followed the advice "*check compiler log*"?

Comment: You've declared a scalar function-- it can only return one thing (a single `varchar2` value in this case.  That seems inconsistent with a desire to "return all values of the emp table".  Are you really trying to create a pipelined table function?  A scalar function that returns a collection?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify your code as much as possible. If you want to return all the attributes of cursor from function, try using BULK collect and return it as complex data type. Here in this case its nested table type. Hope it helps.

```
    --Create a schema level nested table type function

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_obj IS OBJECT
(
EMPNO NUMBER,
ENAME VARCHAR2(100),
SAL NUMBER,
MGR_NO NUMBER,
HIREDATE DATE
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_tab IS TABLE OF emp_obj
/



--Funtion to return all attributes from EMP tab
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMP_value 
RETURN emp_tab
AS
e_tab emp_tab;
begin
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO e_tab
FROM EMP;
RETURN e_tab;
end;
/
```

Comment: Error(6,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(6,34): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Comment: select * bulk collect into e_tab from emp; the entire line show me error;

Comment: Ypu need to define all the columns present in the table emp in the OBJECT type creation.

Comment: Since my emp table has EMPNO NUMBER,
ENAME VARCHAR2(100),
SAL NUMBER,
MGR_NO NUMBER,
HIREDATE DATE columns so i defined it that way. You have to define the OBJECT type as per your emp table